# Rewrite CSS and JS url prepending www wia .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In a wordpress site all my assets are loaded by an URL which not contain the "www".
So CSS and JS files are loaded with this kind of path

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.it/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css" type="text/css">`

Now, I was wondering if it's possible to rewrite via htaccess this urls, by prepending the "www" only to my assets inclusions...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```